# Nuxt 3: Can I use useFetch() in a custom function?

Tags: nuxt3

I have a user create form with email and name input fields. There's also "Submit" button. Can I use `useFetch` in the custom `store` function to make a POST request with user data?

```
const store = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await useFetch('/api/admin/users/store', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: user,
    })
    console.log(error.value.data.errors)
}
```

The endpoint @ `/api/admin/users/store` returns validation errors that look like this:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I properly make a POST request to save a form with few fields in Nuxt 3?

Comment: I ended up using `$fetch` function.